# how can i add 1440x900 resolution on Dell Inspiron 1525 Laptop

Tags: display, dell, resolution, inspiron

I have a 5 year-old Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop, with a display resolution of 1280x800 (16:10).
I wish to increase that resolution to at least 1440x900. Is this possible? If so - how?

[image]

**Chipset:** Intel GM965 Express Chipset.
**Graphics Processor:** integrated Intel GMA X3100 graphics (Previously changed to 965 Express).
**LCD Display:** 15.4" widescreen with a 1280 × 800 resolution, 15.4" widescreen with a 1280 × 800 resolution and TrueLife, or a 15.4" widescreen with a 1440 x 900 high resolution and TrueLife.
(*Wikipedia*)

cheers,

Uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your display's max resolution is 1280x800.

"*15.4" widescreen with a 1440 x 900 high resolution and TrueLife*," [said on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Inspiron_1525#System_specifications), is physically another display for your laptop.

Maybe you could replace your display in service center.